# For some reason the return when I subtract is not correct

Tags: javascript

This is my code. The problem is that the subtraction renders the same return as the variable noDiscount. I have tried to play with multiple methods of subtraction but so far nothing has worked. Also I wanted to know if there was a way of editting font size and font type in java

```
// Variables 
var BREAK = "<br />"
var pricePound = 1.13;           // This is the price per pound
var amountPurchased = 0;         // Number of pounds purchased
var reduceRate = 0;              // This is the percent it is reduced
var noDiscount = pricePound * amountPurchased;     //Cost without discount
var amountSaved = reduceRate * noDiscount;
var reducCost = noDiscount - amountSaved;


 noDiscount = pricePound * amountPurchased
amountSaved = reduceRate * noDiscount
reducCost = noDiscount - amountSaved
document.write ("Hello and thank you for shopping at the ACME cement company. This program is here to handle transaction information and apply discounts. For all other concerns please go to our main site." + BREAK)
window.alert("Please be aware that all cement purchases are on sell and, the more you buy the more it will be discounted!!! All numbers inputted will be converted to pounds. Some restrictions and limitations do apply see a instore clerk for details.")
amountPurchased = parseFloat(prompt("Valued customer, please enter the amount of cement you would like to purchase." ));


parseFloat(amountPurchased)

if (amountPurchased <= 0) {
    window.alert("ERROR. Your purchase is below our minimum purchase amount. Please refresh the page and increase the amount you are trying to purchase." );
} else if (amountPurchased <= 500) {
    reduceRate = 0.02;
} else if (amountPurchased <= 9000) {
    reduceRate = 0.04;  
} else if (amountPurchased <= 15000) {
    reduceRate = 0.05;
} else { //only occurs when none of the others are true: so this is when it's >15000
    reduceRate = 0.09;
};
amountSaved = reduceRate * noDiscount
noDiscount = pricePound * amountPurchased
reducCost = noDiscount - amountSaved
document.write ("Your purchase of " + amountPurchased + "lbs of cement cost $" + noDiscount.toFixed(2) + ". It will be reduced by " +  reduceRate + "% bringing your total to $" + reducCost.toFixed(2));

</script>
```

Comment: Did you try debugging ? Use firefox with `Firebug` plugin - it will output all errors in your javascript. Also, if you want to use function parseFloat then you need to name it as function `function parseFloat() { logic }`

Comment: Thank you for the info on parseFloat I am (very) new to this programming thing and tbh you lost me with the {logic} part all together. My teacher is sexist and hates women thats why he won't explain. and to be honest i have been working on this all day and am to stressed. I keep thinking  I missed something small but can't figure it out Edit--- Scuze the sexist commment please and yes I tried to debug but I did it in chrome using the F12 button (as instructed by proffessor)

Comment: Try removing one line at a time until the problem goes away, then  you'll know the last thing you removed was what caused the problem. As a side benefit, you'll have less code to post here, because as it is, no-one is going to read through dozens of line of your code to help you find a typo or equivalent mistake. Also, don't post the `head` element. We already know it's an HTML page.

Comment: I know the error is only in the subtraction (all other data computes correctly) and sorry bout the head section :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this? I would also separate all this into functions and do so event on button click.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Transaction Invoice</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Caprica" />
    <!-- Date: 2014-11-12 -->
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Program name: Transaction Invoice
// Purpose: To do a transaction
// Author: Ephraim Vickers
// Date last modified: Today

// Variables 
var BREAK = "<br />"

var pricePound = 1.13;           // This is the price per pound
var amountPurchased = 0;         // Number of pounds purchased
var reduceRate = 0;              // This is the percent it is reduced
document.write ("Hello and thank you for shopping at the ACME cement company. This program is here to handle transaction information and apply discounts. For all other concerns please go to our main site." + BREAK)
window.alert("Please be aware that all cement purchases are on sell and, the more you buy the more it will be discounted!!! All numbers inputted will be converted to pounds. Some restrictions and limitations do apply see a instore clerk for details.")
amountPurchased = parseFloat(prompt("Valued customer, please enter the amount of cement you would like to purchase." ));

var noDiscount = pricePound * amountPurchased;     //Cost without discount
var amountSaved = reduceRate * noDiscount;
var reducCost = noDiscount - amountSaved;

parseFloat(amountPurchased)

if (amountPurchased <= 0) {
    window.alert("ERROR. Your purchase is below our minimum purchase amount. Please refresh the page and increase the amount you are trying to purchase." );
} else if (amountPurchased <= 500) {
    reduceRate = 0.02;
} else if (amountPurchased <= 9000) {
    reduceRate = 0.04;  
} else if (amountPurchased <= 15000) {
    reduceRate = 0.05;
} else { //only occurs when none of the others are true: so this is when it's >15000
    reduceRate = 0.09;
};

amountSaved = reduceRate * noDiscount
noDiscount = pricePound * amountPurchased
reducCost = noDiscount - amountSaved
document.write ("Your purchase of " + amountPurchased + "lbs of cement cost $" + noDiscount.toFixed(2) + ". It will be reduced by " +  reduceRate + "% bringing your total to $" + reducCost.toFixed(2));

</script>
```

So this would be a rather better solution:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Transaction Invoice</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Caprica" />
    <!-- Date: 2014-11-12 -->

    <div>Hello and thank you for shopping at the ACME cement company. This program is here to handle transaction information and apply discounts. For all other concerns please go to our main site.</div>
    <div>Please be aware that all cement purchases are on sell and, the more you buy the more it will be discounted!!! All numbers inputted will be converted to pounds. Some restrictions and limitations do apply see a instore clerk for details.</div>
    <button onclick="Calculate();">New Order</button>
    <div id='msg'></div>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Program name: Transaction Invoice
        // Purpose: To do a transaction
        // Author: Ephraim Vickers
        // Date last modified: Today

        var pricePound = 1.13; // This is the price per pound
        var amountPurchased = 0; // Number of pounds purchased
        var reduceRate = 0; // This is the percent it is reduced

        var noDiscount = 0; //pricePound * amountPurchased;     //Cost without discount
        var amountSaved = 0; //reduceRate * noDiscount;
        var reducCost = 0; // noDiscount - amountSaved;

        function parseFloat(amountPurchased) {

            if (amountPurchased <= 0) {
                reduceRate = 0;
                //window.alert("ERROR. Your purchase is below our minimum purchase amount. Please refresh the page and increase the amount you are trying to purchase." );
            } else if (amountPurchased <= 500) {
                reduceRate = 0.02;
            } else if (amountPurchased <= 9000) {
                reduceRate = 0.04;
            } else if (amountPurchased <= 15000) {
                reduceRate = 0.05;
            } else { //only occurs when none of the others are true: so this is when it's >15000
                reduceRate = 0.09;
            }
            return;
        }


        function Calculate() {
            //set zeroes for all values
            amountPurchased = 0;
            reduceRate = 0;
            noDiscount = 0;
            amountSaved = 0;
            reducCost = 0;

            //get user input
            amountPurchased = prompt("Valued customer, please enter the amount of cement you would like to purchase.");
            parseFloat(amountPurchased);

            //calculate discount
            noDiscount = pricePound * amountPurchased; //Cost without discount
            amountSaved = reduceRate * noDiscount;
            reducCost = noDiscount - amountSaved;

            // output data
            if (reduceRate === 0) {
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "ERROR. Your purchase is below our minimum purchase amount. Please refresh the page and increase the amount you are trying to purchase.";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Your purchase of " + amountPurchased + "lbs of cement cost $" + noDiscount.toFixed(2) + ". It will be reduced by " + reduceRate + "% bringing your total to $" + reducCost.toFixed(2)
            }

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: I can't figure out what was changed >.<

Comment: Why do you redefine [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)?

Answer (score 1):

In a computer program the order of the commands is important. In your program
you first compute reducCost from amountPurchased, and THEN you get the input
from the user and store it in amountPurchased.

But the computation has already finished, and  reducCost  will not be changed by
this input.

Comment: This did not fix it :( but thanks for the foresight next time

Comment: what did you change to fix it?  You can edit the post to show the new code